# Xcode Server 11 Export Archive Fails

Tags: xcode-server

The 11.x series of Xcode seems to have broken Xcode Server. Every bot that is configured to output an archive at the end of processing now fails.

The raw output log looks like the following:

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --entitlements /Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/00e9c33f477939d77900feeab0004e34/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Pocket\ Bot/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pocket\ Bot.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pocket\ Bot.build/Pocket\ Bot.app.xcent /Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/00e9c33f477939d77900feeab0004e34/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Pocket\ Bot/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Pocket\ Bot.app  


RegisterExecutionPolicyException /Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/00e9c33f477939d77900feeab0004e34/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Pocket\ Bot/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Pocket\ Bot.app (in target 'Pocket Bot' from project 'Pocket Bot')  
    cd /Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/00e9c33f477939d77900feeab0004e34/Source/PocketBot  
    builtin-RegisterExecutionPolicyException /Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/00e9c33f477939d77900feeab0004e34/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Pocket\ Bot/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Pocket\ Bot.app  


Touch /Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/00e9c33f477939d77900feeab0004e34/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Pocket\ Bot/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Pocket\ Bot.app (in target 'Pocket Bot' from project 'Pocket Bot')  
    cd /Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/00e9c33f477939d77900feeab0004e34/Source/PocketBot  
    /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/00e9c33f477939d77900feeab0004e34/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Pocket\ Bot/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Pocket\ Bot.app  
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **  




$ /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath /Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Integration-00e9c33f477939d77900feeab000a7a2/Pocket Bot.xcarchive -exportPath /Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Integration-00e9c33f477939d77900feeab000a7a2/ExportedProduct -exportOptionsPlist /Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Integration-00e9c33f477939d77900feeab000a7a2/ExportOptions.plist -IDEPostProgressNotifications=YES -DVTAllowServerCertificates=YES -DVTProvisioningUseServerAccounts=YES -allowProvisioningUpdates  


2019-12-23 08:02:56.486 xcodebuild[42941:4409262] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/zp/h393vgwn2798zhzdv9kz0hrw0000gq/T/Pocket Bot_2019-12-23_08-02-56.486.xcdistributionlogs'.  
2019-12-23 08:02:56.507 xcodebuild[42941:4409262] [MT] IDEDistributionMethodManager: -[IDEDistributionMethodManager orderedDistributionMethodsForTask:archive:]: Error = Error Domain=IDEDistributionMethodManagerErrorDomain Code=2 "Unknown Distribution Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Distribution Error}  
2019-12-23 08:02:56.507 xcodebuild[42941:4409262] [MT] IDEDistributionMethodManager: -[IDEDistributionMethodManager orderedDistributionMethodsForTask:archive:]: Error = Error Domain=IDEDistributionMethodManagerErrorDomain Code=2 "Unknown Distribution Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Distribution Error}  
error: exportArchive: Found no compatible export methods for: <DVTFilePath:0x7ff5996eb5f0:'/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Integration-00e9c33f477939d77900feeab000a7a2/Pocket Bot.xcarchive'>  


Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Found no compatible export methods for: <DVTFilePath:0x7ff5996eb5f0:'/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Integration-00e9c33f477939d77900feeab000a7a2/Pocket Bot.xcarchive'>" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found no compatible export methods for: <DVTFilePath:0x7ff5996eb5f0:'/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Integration-00e9c33f477939d77900feeab000a7a2/Pocket Bot.xcarchive'>}  


** EXPORT FAILED **
```

This bot worked before the update to Xcode 11, and now does not. I've even created a new bot, on an entirely different server, and it has the same outcome.

An examination of the path '/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder' reveals there are no integrations assets at that level, but there are 'Bot' folders. I'm wondering if the export path is missing the 'Bots/{UUID}' component.

Anyone have any suggestions or possible fixes?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have confirmed though, that the integration folder path, and archive are created during the integration, but the export still fails. So effectively my Xcode Server is useless.